# Значение и аналог слова Bulk на русском языке

Tags: сеть, терминология

Что могут значить слова Bulk и Bulk rate относительно компьютерных сетей (сетевого пакета)?

Comment: Большой объём (данных). Скорость передачи/загрузки объёма данных.